# Linq - Where().Where() is AND or OR?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In this query:

```
var test = db.table.Where(x=>x.id == x).Where(x=>x.name == name).ToList();
```

It is the same of using AND or OR in SQL language?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: this is going to be a AND

Comment: If you filter half the elements out of a list, and then look at the *resulting list*, how many of the filtered-out elements do you expect to find in the filtered list? a) Zero b) None c) Not Any d) Maybe some little ones snuck under the turnstile?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think D is correct answer.

Comment: @Euphoric Slippery little buggers...

Comment: Do you mean "What does this statement translate into SQL when using Linq-to-SQL"?

Comment: In case it's not clear, the downvotes are because: *This question does not show any research effort* (hover over the downvote icon to see it)

Comment: Why would you do something like that in the first place? If you want AND, just do x.id == id && x.name == name, if you want OR just do x.id == id || x.name == name.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - dynamic composition of queries is one of the great features of Linq. In real code it just wouldn't be on one line.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I agree, it's just that this particular example seems pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as doing two separated operations:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var biggerThanThree = numbers.Where(x => x > 3); // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

var smallerThanSeven = biggerThanThree.Where(x => x < 7); // [4, 5, 6]
```

I'm not going into lazy execution here, to keep things simple.

But the second `.Where` operates on the list already filtered by the first `.Where`, so it acts as an AND

Answer (score 8):

AND.

But you can use

**AND**

```
var test = db.table.Where(x=>x.id == x && x.name == name).ToList();
```

**OR**

```
var test = db.table.Where(x=>x.id == x || x.name == name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), I ran the following linq expression against one of my databases:

`Personnels.Where(x => x.LastName == "Doe").Where(x => x.FirstName == "John")`

Which results in the following t-sql:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'John'
DECLARE @p1 VarChar(1000) = 'Doe'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName]
FROM [Personnel] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[FirstName] = @p0) AND ([t0].[LastName] = @p1)
```

Which is pretty much the same t-sql generated by this linq expression:

`Personnels.Where(x => x.LastName == "Doe" && x.FirstName == "John")`

result:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Doe'
DECLARE @p1 VarChar(1000) = 'John'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName]
FROM [Personnel] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[LastName] = @p0) AND ([t0].[FirstName] = @p1)
```

So yes, at least in simple cases, it is the same as AND. IMHO, however, using the && operator is better than chaining multiple .Where() calls. If you can't have multiple WHERE clauses in SQL, you shouldn't be chaining multiple .Where() clauses in your ORM.